# Is there a secure shell client for Mac similar to Secure CRT for Windows?

Tags: software-recommendation, ssh, switching

I have many servers to manage and I don't want to use Terminal on my Mac to keep and manage server lists.

I want to know if there is a secure shell client for Mac similar to [Secure CRT on Windows](http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html)?

Answer (score 4):

How about SecureCRT for Mac? http://www.vandyke.com/products/beta/securecrt/mac_osx.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm a great fan of [ZOC Terminal Emulator for MacOS](https://www.emtec.com/zoc/).

It has a host list, tabbed interface, very similar features. The two programs (ZOC and SecCRT) appear to copy-cat each other's features always within a few months.  Like SecureCRT, ZOC Terminal is commercial.

See also this [question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/105959/macos-terminal-alternative-replacement-like-securecrt-ssh-client-mac-os-x) on superuser (the guy there quotes someone saying it's the closest thing to SecureCRT).  User comments on [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30267/zoc-terminal) are mostly favorable.

.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I use [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) in the way I used to use SecureCRT. In particular, if you set up profiles then you can pick machines off a list and have a single button click / hotkey open up a shell on the chosen remote machine. To set up a profile this way:

1. Run iTerm2 and select Profiles / Open Profiles.
2. Click "Edit Profiles" to bring up the Preferences pane.
3. Click the + button in lower left to create a new profile.
4. Name your profile however you want, like the remote hostname.
5. Click the Command radio button, and set the command to `ssh [hostname]`.
6. (Optional) configure other options for just this profile, like colors, terminal behavior, etc. You can also set a shortcut key.

Now when you want to log in to your remote machine, just select Open Profiles (or press Cmd-O) and click your machine name. There are buttons to open the session in a new tab or new window.

Technically this is a little different than SecureCRT; it's not sshing directly from iTerm2, it creates a tty on your local machine first and runs the ssh command in it. That design is harmless and in many ways a virtue; you get Keychain integration for your ssh credentials, for instance.

Comment: I use profiles in iTerm2 much the same way. As a way to do one click ssh access to different hosts.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Tagged Profiles](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/profiles) of iTerm2?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but it looks like [JellyfiSSH](http://www.m-works.co.nz/jellyfissh.php) might do what you're looking for. $4 on the Mac App store. There's also [SSHMenu](http://www.marinhobrandao.com/sshmenu/) which looks less polished, but you can get it for free if you want to compile it yourself, or $1 on the App store.